# Correct way to put a MySQL replicated environment safely into maintenance mode?

Tags: mysql, mysql-replication

I need to perform some maintenance on our master/slave/slave MySQL cluster. The maintenance involves optimising three tables, at least one of which is being locked for a duration of approximately 2 hours. The optimise operation for each table runs to completion  on the master and then propagates to the slaves in turn via the binary log when complete.

The way I see it I currently have 3 options:

1. Restart master with `skip-networking`, run the optimise and then bring it back online afterwards and allow the slaves to catch up.
2. Bring all 3 nodes offline concurrently, run the optimise operations in parallel in parallel, and reset replication afterwards.
3. Cleanly stop MySQL on the nodes, shut off networking to the outside world, bring them back up, run the optimise on master and allow it to propagate to the slaves before restoring network access.

I’m struggling to find any documentation on best practices for this, or the exact behaviour of the shutdown, is anybody able to confirm the best way to safely bring the boxes offline to perform the necessary work?

Performing the operation cleanly is of bigger concern than the time taken, as the maintenance will be performed overnight.

The MySQL version is 5.6, it unfortunately is an older version, plans are in place to upgrade in the near future but I’m stuck with it for the time being.  The replication method is GTID.

Many thanks.

Comment: (should be in dba.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Noted for next time, I wasn't aware that subdomain existed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, do you *really* need to run `OPTIMIZE TABLE`?  In most situations, InnoDB keeps its tables clean enough to never need Optimize.  If you are using MyISAM, you should convert to InnoDB for a variety of reasons.

If the Optimize is because you did a big `DELETE`, then [next time] do the Delete in a less intrusive way, which may eliminate the need to Optimize.  See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig .

OK, back to your question.  There is a replication setting that prevents the propagation of commands to the Replicas.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set-sql-log-bin.html  So, do this on the Primary:

```
# when logged in with sufficient privileges:
SET sql_log_bin = OFF;
OPTIMIZE TABLE ...;
SET sql_log_bin = ;
```

Then go through the Replicas, one at a time:
Take a Replica offline and manually run `OPTIMIZE`.  Put back online.

Comment: Yes, running the optimise freed up approx 175GBytes of disk space, it absolutely needed doing. I'm uncertain what the original cause of the fragmentation was as it predates my time at the company concerned, but it was extensive, despite the tables being InnoDB.

Thanks for this, I have since completed the optimisation work, but I sourced the same solution as above through other means and it worked perfectly, allowing me to run the optimisations on all nodes concurrently to keep the maintenance time down.